# Specify the API version using an Advanced Service within Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-content-api

I need to use version 2.1 of the Content API within my script however, I'm unsure how to pass the version number.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
    pageToken: pageToken,
    maxResults: maxResults,
    includeInvalidInsertedItems: true
});
```

I've tried passing `version: 2.1` but no cigar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version for a particular client library is specified only when you are [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) a particular advanced service. Not all versions are supported by all client libraries e.g. the [`Drive` advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) does not support the v3 endpoints.

For the [`ShoppingContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/shopping-content) client library, Apps Script provides bindings only to version 2:

[image]

Thus, to use v2.1, you will need to treat the Shopping Content API as an [external API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external), and access it using `UrlFetchApp`. You will need to authorize the requests as appropriate, constructing your own [OAuth2 authorization header](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re) with the [`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) method, e.g.:

```
function addAuthHeader(headers) {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
function getBaseURI(version) {
  return 'https://www.googleapis.com/content/' + version + '/';
}

function listProducts(merchantId, pageToken) {
  const base = getBaseURI('v2.1');
  const path = merchantId + '/products';
  if (pageToken)
    path + '?pageToken=' + pageToken;

  const headers = {
    /* whatever you need here */
  };
  addAuthHeader(headers);

  const fetchOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    /* whatever else you need here
      https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params
     */
    headers: headers
  };
  var pageResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(base + path, fetchOptions);
  var onePageOfResults = JSON.parse(pageResponse.getContentText());
  /* whatever else */
}
```